# How to adjust the handlebar alignment with front wheel?

Tags: handlebars, headset, stem

I have the follwing stem

[image]

My handlebar is a bit too much right and I am not sure what screw(s) I have to loosen the one on top (in the [headset](https://www.rosebikes.de/artikel/acros-ah-34e-steuersatz/aid:718965?channable=e8277.NzE4OTY1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMInPGglqLz2AIVyArTCh2wfgW6EAQYASABEgJ0d_D_BwE)) or the two left on the picture above or maybe all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying the handlebars are angled to the right of being straight. You will want to loosen the two screws that are going horizontal across the steering tube. then you can straighten the handlebar/stem combo and re-tighten.
 Be careful there are sometime torque spec on the Stem to make sure you don't strip it.
[image]

Comment: And don't loosen the one on the top since it will alter the pre-loading on the headset and affect the steering. Check the www.parktool.com/ web-site or youtube. You'll find information on the subject.